# Relation convergence in probability and Almost Sure convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I want to show that some sequence of events $A_n$ happens almost always, that is $\mathbb{P}(\{A_n\} \text{ a.a.}) = 1$, which is equivalent to showing  $\mathbb{P}(\{A_n^C\} \text{ i.o.}) = 0$. I could use Borell-Cantelli's second lemma, but there is one problem:

The following series does not necessarily converge: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_n^C) $. What we do now however, is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n^C) = 0$.

Thus my intuition tells me that perhaps convergence in probability could play a role here, but then the question arises: To what does it converge to in probability then?

Comment: There is somewhat of a converse to Borel-Cantelli by the way. If $E_1,E_2,\dots$ are pairwise independent and $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(E_n) = \infty$, then $E_n$ occurs infinitely often. In your setting, $E_n = A_n^c$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am aware of that fact, unfortunately, in our case, the events are not independent.

Comment: Convergence in probability deals with random variables. But, you have events. What do you mean when you say “it converges in probability.” What converges? Note also that if probabilities go to zero, that does not mean they sum to a finite number. So the given info cannot help you reach your goal. However you can conclude that $P[A_i \quad i.o.]=1$.